# Use conan binary dependencies for Python wheel package

Tags: python, python-wheel, conan

I have a C++ library project. This project is build by conan. Also I have a Python wrapper for the first project. The python project is built by setuptools.

How can setuptools pull the native library from conan repo to include in into the wheel (*.whl) file?
Or is it possible to make a wheel file using conan?

I've found this solution: https://blog.conan.io/2016/12/12/Conan-python-package-manager.html
But in this solution conan does not create a wheel file to distribute the package.

Comment: Conan 2.0 will have a public documented Python API (Conan 1.X has one, but not public, though some people seem to be using it). Maybe calling the api from setup.py is possible to automate?

Comment: Conan is not focused in Python distribution, but you can create a new Generator and make it generate whatever you need. If you need a wheel file, you could add a new generator to create it: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/custom_generators.html. On the other hand, you could use `Deploy` generator to copy those pre-built libraries to your folder: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/deploy.html